# Why does glob promise return an empty string array?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, path, glob

I am only using typescript, ts-node, npm and path

I am simply trying to return a string array of files defined by my pattern using glob-promise (An npm that I imported which uses glob but its promise based).

I created a custom npm script to run my ts file for the terminal to display info in my package.json below

```
{
"name": "glob-test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A Glob Test",
"scripts": {
    "build:glob": "ts-node --files globby.ts"
},
"dependencies": {
    "glob-promise": "^6.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
}
```

}

And this below is my globby.ts file which runs the glob script

```
import * as path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob-promise';

const dir = path.dirname(__dirname);
    const txtURL = path.resolve(dir, 'glob-test', 'folder-area', '*.txt');

    glob(txtURL).then(function (cnt) {
    console.log('Path: ' + txtURL);
    console.log('Content: ', cnt);
});
```

My project directory looks like so:

[image]

I type in my terminal npm run build:glob but it returns an empty array and the path displays correctly I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I've attempted to use path.join and path.resolve but either give the same result. It should return the joke.txt file. Anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Are you *sure* the path is right? Looking at that code and directory layout, I'd expect it to have `glob-test` doubled up.

Comment: Yes I’m sure, I actually added the “glob-test” because without it, it actually skips the root directory entirely for some reason in the full path that it outputs in console.log. It seems that ```path.dirname(__dirname)``` does that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is that the path module with the glob-promise module are not playing nice in my windows environment. If I use a normal string with or without concats glob will return perfectly anything I ask.

This seems to be a bug/issue or incompatibility within the windows environment most likely. Yet to test on Linux.

e.g: Works below

```
import * as path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob-promise';

// const dir = path.dirname(__dirname);
const txtURL = path.resolve('folder-area', '*.txt');
const testURL = './folder-area/*.txt';

const returnTxtFiles = async () => {
const txtFiles = await glob(testURL);
console.log(txtFiles);
};

returnTxtFiles();
```

The above correctly returns `['joke.txt', 'file1.txt']`

The other option is replace all the '/' to '' manually to any `path.join("string", "string")` by adding at the end `.replace(/\\/g, "/")`

Which is the method I went with as it took much less work adn I think is more understandable as well as it changes the original codebase the least.

Comment: It looks lhis is expected behavior. `glob-promise` is just a promise wrapper on top of `glob`, and `glob` says to [always use forward slashes, even on Windows](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#windows). Because `path.resolve` uses `path.sep`, that's throwing `glob` off.